# .removeClass() let class attribute on html tag

Tags: jquery, html

My html looks something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="image1.jpg" class="current" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Doing `$("#container").find('img[class="current"]').removeClass("current")` my html becomes:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="image1.jpg" class />
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
</div>
```

My question is : Does the fact that the img tag contains `class` (attribute, it's not really an attribute beacause he has no value assigned to it, right ?) it's something that I should care of ? It's a valid code, HTML5 speaking ?

Comment: Each DOM element has `class` property which by default is set to an empty string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're ever wondering if a bit of code is valid, you can use the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/). It's a fantastic tool.

In HTML5, empty attributes are [technically valid](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes), although, in practice, they should be reserved for "boolean attributes" (such as the `disabled` attribute for form fields). The empty class in the code snippet you provided does not cause any validation errors for HTML5.

In XHTML4.01 it is technically not permitted to have empty attributes (booleans had to be set like `disabled="true"`), however, browsers have supported empty attributes for the sake of booleans for a long time now.

Comment: Just want to point out that if you enter a URI into the W3C validation tool, then it will not validate any changes to the DOM resulting from JavaScript. You will need to copy/paste the full modified mark-up after JS has made modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it'll work fine -- all still valid HTML5.

`class` is still an attribute, but it is an attribute with no value.

Answer (score 0):

It should result like this:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" class="" />
```

And there's nothing wrong with html...

Comment: But it results in `class`, not `class=""`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8xy297e/).

Comment: In your fiddle I'm seeing class=""

Comment: Whatever they are valid in html and html5 too.

Comment: It's going to come down to vender-specific browser differences. There is no W3C spec on how a tag attribute is set to null.

Comment: In chrome 37.0.2062.103 it results in `class`.

Comment: @ElliotB. yeah, it looks so. I have `class` both in my Opera and Chrome.

Comment: If so, that might be vendor problem, but as far as I know class="" would be only valid in html but just using class would be bad practice...

Comment: I just tested in chrome it's making me no sense as it's using <anything anything anything></anything asdf jlkjl> so, it's not good practice really...